# Exclude parts of the org-mode content based on export filetype

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-reveal

I work with org-reveal for presentations and export to LaTeX based PDF for handouts.

I use SVG for the graphs in the reveal-presentation for better scaling and I want those to be ignored when exporting to LaTeX-PDF. Instead a PDF should be used. There are also some slides I want to have in the presentation but are not necessary for the handout.

Is there a way to exclude parts of the tree from export, e.g., `:noexport:`, based on the export filetype?

Comment: Are the graphs pre-made and already available in SVG and PDF format? Or are the graphs supposed to be produced when you are exporting the file?

Comment: They are already pre-made and are only loaded into the the export.

Answer (score 0):

Since the graphs are pre-made, you can use export blocks to include the appropriate version for the appropriate export (IIRC, `ox-reveal` defines an exporter that's derived from HTML, hence the `html` tag in the block below):

```
#+BEGIN_EXPORT html
[[file:/path/to/img.svg][An SVG image]]
#+END_EXPORT

#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex
[[file:/path/to/img.pdf][A PDF image]]
#+END_EXPORT
```

A bit ugly and repetitive, but it can be automated in the longer run.